# Primefaces TreeTable css style

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, treetable

In my JSF web application I've inserted a simple [TreeTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf).

Where can I set up distance between left border and expanded child's icon? 
I want this distance to be bigger when new level is expanded.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/treetable.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-treetable .ui-treetable-indent {
                float: right;
                height: 0px;
                width: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>        
        <h:form id="form">  

            <p:treeTable value="#{newJSFManagedBean.docCon.root}" var="document"  
                         selection="#{newJSFManagedBean.docCon.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single">  

                <f:facet name="header">  
                    Single Selection  
                </f:facet>  

                <p:column style="width:150px">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Name  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column style="width:100px">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Size  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.size}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column style="width:100px">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Type  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{document.type}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <f:facet name="footer">  
                    <p:commandButton id="singleBtn" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"  
                            update=":form:documentPanel" oncomplete="documentDialog.show()"/>  
                </f:facet>  
            </p:treeTable>  

            <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Document Detail" showEffect="fade" widgetVar="documentDialog" modal="true">  
                <p:outputPanel id="documentPanel">  
                    <h:panelGrid  columns="2" cellpadding="5" rendered="#{not empty newJSFManagedBean.docCon.selectedNode}">  
                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name: " />  
                        <h:outputText id="name" value="#{newJSFManagedBean.docCon.selectedNode.data.name}" style="font-weight:bold" />  

                        <h:outputLabel for="size" value="Size: " />  
                        <h:outputText id="size" value="#{newJSFManagedBean.docCon.selectedNode.data.size}" style="font-weight:bold" />  

                        <h:outputLabel for="type" value="Type " />  
                        <h:outputText id="type" value="#{newJSFManagedBean.docCon.selectedNode.data.type}" style="font-weight:bold" />  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:outputPanel>  
            </p:dialog>  

        </h:form>          
        <br /><br />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own css and override the `ui-treetable-indent` css property originaly defined as :

```
.ui-treetable .ui-treetable-indent {
    float: left;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

The simple way is to include your own stylesheet with `h:outputStylesheet` or `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: I think it doesn't work. I have created css dir and css file inside. Then in head put <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/treetable.css" />. Doesn't work. 

How to use it in styleClass or style attribute, so it has impact only on treetable ?

Comment: Are you sure of your `href`? When you display the source from your browser, do it resolve the css? However it seems not possible to use styleClass. The best way to narrow the impact on treetable is to use css feature, eg. embed the treetable inside a container with a specific class

Comment: In EDIT I've inserted my xhtml code. I tried without link too. As you can see I changed to right and put 0px to see some changes. But I don't.

Comment: Which version of primefaces do you use? It can have an impact on css style name

Comment: `.ui-treetable .ui-treetable-indent` is a new Primefaces 3.5 style. Prior 3.5, the indentation is set as a inline style of a generated div. Difficult to modify. To view style and html structure you can use firefox firebug addons or chrome native developer tools (F12 key).

Comment: ok. Thanks for help. btw. is there any doc that will describe Treetable control. I mean - to change row height override this css property etc etc ?

Comment: The only reference is primefaces [documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html). This reference is not complete. It is better to use it with css inspection and code inspection from [svn](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/treetable/treetable.css).